# PyroCMS PayPal IPN Seems not being triggered by PayPal

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn, pyrocms

i am having an anonymous issue with PayPal IPN.i am working on a simple event booking system and using PayPal Standard as Payment Gateway.

When i make payment in sandbox mode it goes through but PayPal never hit my IPN url which is http://www.xxxx.xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/ipn

in my IPN Function i'm only logging the message which just write "ipn is triggered" when i hit my ipn url it simply logs message but when i make payment(sandbox mode) it never logs message.

Can you Please help me out to sort this out i already have wasted 4 days just to resolve this issue and still no Luck :(

Comment: i have carefully checked the notify_url URL which is same as i posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue earlier today, you can view the status of that issue [here](https://www.x.com/content/correction-delay-receiving-instant-payment-notifications-ipns-mar-16).  Also, have you tried checking your IPN history from within the account you have this set up on.  The IPN history should show if the IPN is being sent out.  The history will show if it was sent out successfully, if it failed or if it is in a retrying status.  If it shows as failed, you could try checking the details of that IPN message and see if it is showing what status code is being returned to PayPal.  This may help to determine where the issue is at.  This page [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/ipn-troubleshooting-tips-0) may also help you in troubleshooting the isue as well.